# How to encrypt laravel 5.2 URL or Routes?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I need to encrypt routes in this URL? Because I do not want user to access URL by changing the item id. For example, user can change /items/1234 to /item/5678. Although item 1234 and 5678 belong to the same user, I still want to restrict the behavior. What I am trying to do is encrypting the routes but I am not sure whether this is a proper way or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can't encypt it inside routes, you encrypt it inside your controller

Comment: "Although item 1234 and 5678 belong to the same user, I still want to restrict the behavior". Why?

Comment: If there is actually some issue/use case of doing this then please make a middleware with that use case

Comment: You may provide alias to the route and encrypt the parameters.

Comment: I'm stuck to similar requirement now.. How did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 15):

You can encrypt your url parameter and decrypt it in your controller. You can try this:

In your view: Suppose your parameter is id or more parameter you can encrypt.

```
<?php
        $parameter =[
            'id' =>1,
        ];
    $parameter= Crypt::encrypt($parameter);
?>
<a href="{{url('/url/',$parameter)}}" target="_blank">a link</a>
```

Your route will be:

```
Route::get('/url/{parameter}', 'YourController@methodName');
```

In your controller, You can decrypt your parameter:

```
public function methodName($id){
    $data = Crypt::decrypt($id);
  }
```

You must be yous Crypt namespace in your top of controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
```

Note: You can encrypt url parameter with `Crypt::encrypt($parameter)` and decrypt with  `Crypt::decrypt($parameter)`

Comment: is it possible to can i encrypt the routes?

Comment: You can encrypt all parameter from view passing through routes/url . Just decrypt parameter in controller. That's it. –

Comment: Yes you are right but I want encrypt  parameters as well as routes.

Comment: May be You can not encrypt routes inside routes. Only you can encrypt from view and controller.

Answer (score 5):

One way you could mitigate this issue would be to use Universally Unique ID's (UUID).

You will no longer have the issue of auto-increment database crawling and a user cannot alter URL's to get different data.

You can quite easily change your database to support this in your migrations by changing your id column from

this:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

to this:

```
$table->uuid('id')->primary();
```

Your model can then be edited to support the non incrementing primary key by adding the following to your class:

```
protected $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: This is definitely the better way to tackle the issue, you are sticking to normal conventions however giving a more robust way to protect your user id's

Answer (score 3):

You can encrypt the route in your controller while redirecting, using

`\Crypt::encrypt(product_id)`

and on the product page you can decrypt the product ID from the URL using

`$product_id = \Crypt::decrypt($url_parameter)`

that's the best possible way.

But there will be some chances of exception if the user Edit's the Product ID parameter from the URL which you will need to handle.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to encrypt all routes, it's bad practice. You can use `encrypt()` helper to encrypt parameter and `decrypt()` to decrypt it.

```
$encryptedId = encrypt($id);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/encryption#using-the-encrypter

Answer (score 1):

You require encrypt URL ID/Any URL param and this is called id obfuscation. You can do it with [hashids library](http://hashids.org/). it converts an integer like *347* to *yr8* and back again.

**Include this library**:

```
composer require hashids/hashids
```

You can get all other easy stuff from [Easy id obfuscation with Laravel 5](http://jenssegers.com/64/easy-id-obfuscation-with-laravel-5)

*This will help you to encrypt URL id*:

```
http://example.com/users/123
```

TO

```
http://example.com/users/Mj3
```

Hope this will help you well!

Comment: I want my url like this for example `http://example.com/users/Mj3` to  `http://example.com/hjksdhsdfssdf8/Mj3`

Comment: I don't think its necessary to include a package for this simple function. If the asker was to go down this route, surely it would be better to create a simple function in the application which is not as heavy as the package which you suggest.

Comment: @JoshBolton you are right, but this is what something different. You can take example like youtube URL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to encrypt the whole route. It may not be good practice but here's how to do it. You will have one controller that receives all requests. All business logic will need to be placed in your services.

1. In route file have a route that points to "/{encrypted}" and to a controller@method (name is up to you).
2. In controller method, decrypt the encrypted param. Maybe the decrypted string is "item/100". Then you'll need to `$routeParams = explode('/', $decrypted);` and send it to a service to process it. e.g.

`if($routeParams[0] == 'item') {
    return ItemService::get($routeParams[1]);
}`

That's the basic idea. But in practice, you would a have handler class that manages the routing your encrypted URL. In this handler class, you'll need to have a config array that functions similarly to Laravel's route file.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give a procedure that worked well for me. Pardon me if the subject is not relevant currently. But if it is, note the following steps i took to solve the problem with a personal project

1. **This is the view where i encrypted the id of say a blog_id/service_id/product_id**

   > `<a href=" {{ route('blogs.show', ['id'=> Crypt::encrypt($blog->id),'slug' => Str::slug($blog->title) ]) }}">`
2. **With the above we then modify our route(web.php) as below**

> `Route::get('/blog_feed/{id}','BlogController@show')->name('blogs.show');`

3. Finally, in your controller, you will perform a **route model binding step**

   > `public function show($id)`
   >
   > > ```
   > > {
   > >    $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);
   > >    $blog = Blog::where('id', $id)->first();
   > >    $user = User::where('id', $blog->user_id)->first();
   > >    return view('blogs.show', compact('blog', 'user'));
   > > }
   > > ```

Hope it helps for future searches