# How can I change the URL structure in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I currently have my URL like this 
`/localhost/products/products_id` e.g. `/localhost/products/4`

But I want it to pick unique_id value from the table's column and show URL like `/localhost/products/unique_id`. e.g. `/localhost/products/l6ye4h9`

Comment: Take a look in your `routes/web.php` file and update your question with some examples.

Comment: Nothing. If there is a route for `id` value which is not filtered as an `integer`, same route will be applicable for `unique_id`.
You have to change your `controller` code to interpret the param as `unique_id`

Comment: Please check the Reference Link
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276128/how-to-encrypt-laravel-5-2-url-or-routes)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to use another attribute for URL generation.

For this you need to rewrite the **getRouteKeyName()** function for your model and tell it to use another attribute.
Ex.:

```php
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'unique_id';
    }
```

By default Laravel is using your model's primary key for URL generation.